# RegEx to match a pattern and exclude a part of the string

Tags: java, regex

I have got some strings to be matched via RegEx. We have a java application which reads the regex from a config file and takes two groups of strings, number of which are specified in the same config.

E.g.

```
CustomAction.523274ca945f.dialogLabel=Executing Custom Code...
```

will be matched with

```
(?m)^(?!#)\s*(\S*)\s*=\s*(\S*.*)
```

What I need is to pick the first group "`CustomAction.523274ca945f.dialogLabel`" and exclude the random string in the middle so I end up with something like "`CustomAction.dialogLabel`" or "`CustomAction..dialogLabel`" well any other combination but the random string.

I don't have the source for the java application I am using.  This is an app for which I can create a config file in which I specify a pattern and two groups and app picks them

```
pattern: (?m)^(?!#)\\s*([^.=\\s]*)\\.(?:[^.=\\s]*\\.)?([^.=\\s]*)\\s*=\\s*(.*?)\\s*$
key_group:  1
value_group:    2
```

I can only specify one group per key and one per value. According to this pattern app picks the key_group to be the key and value_group to be the value for it.

I don't want the garbage in the middle as it is random this changes the key every time.

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches; first assuming your property is three items long a simple replacement of your first (\S*) with:

```
(\S+?)\.\S+?\.(\S+)
```

Note I also changed the * to + since it doesn't make sense to have ".." as part of a property, I've also used non-greedy qualifiers, but it should still work fine without them. Then you can just use the appropriate group numbers to reconstruct the adjusted property. A second approach assuming that your random string is a hex number (which it appears to be) and the non-random portions of the property do not include numbers:

```
((?:\S+.)*)(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]+.)?((?:\S+.?)+)
```

So the first group should pickup everything before the random number (including a trailing dot) the second group will eat the random number, and then the third will match the remaining string (or the whole thing if there is no random number portion).

**EDIT**

With the updated description of the problem and only matching two groups my answer is this is not possible. In a regular expression there is no mechanism to "erase" part of a match. From the problem definition the part of the key that is not to be included is in the middle of other text i.e. the general pattern to match is:

```
((a)(?:b)(c))
```

Since we can not pre or post-process "b" will always be a part of the larger match group that includes both a and c, the fact that it is a non-matching group does not effect the larger group.

Comment: Hi, I need the result be first and third group concatenated not in different groups.  In an app I have I can specify two groups only, one for the Key and one for the value.

Answer (score 0):

The specification isn't very clear, but here's what I'm going to assume:

- `#` at the beginning of the line is a comment
- The "key" can have up to 3 parts, separated by a literal `.`

  - The middle part is an optional "garbage"
- The "key" is followed by `=`, then the "value"
- `.` and `=` are special markers at least until the "value" part, where then everything goes
- Allow whitespaces

Then perhaps the pattern is something like this works:

```
    String text = 
        "  some.stuff.here  =    blah blah  \n" +
        "  awesome.key  =    { level = 10 }  \n" +
        "# awesome.key  =    { level = 11 }  \n" +
        "  awesome..key =    { level = 12 }  \n" +
        "  !@#$.)(*&.$%& =   a=b=c.d=f ";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
        "(?m)^(?!#) (key)@(?:key@)?(key) = (value) $"
            .replace("@", "\\.")
            .replace(" ", "\\s*")
            .replace("key", "[^.=\\s]*")
            .replace("value", ".*?")
    );

    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.printf("%s.%s => [%s]%n",
            m.group(1),
            m.group(2),
            m.group(3)
        );
    }
```

This prints:

```
some.here => [blah blah]
awesome.key => [{ level = 10 }]
awesome.key => [{ level = 12 }]
!@#$.$%& => [a=b=c.d=f]
```

Note the `replace` approach to generate the final regex pattern; it's used to enhance readability of the overall big picture "pattern"

Comment: I am sorry, I should have been more precise. I am updating the question