# Regular Expression: Capture character pattern zero or one positions from start of string

Tags: regex, bash

I have a series of entries, which can be represented by this string:

`my_string="-D-K4_NNNN_M116_R1_001.gz _D-K4_NNNN_M56_R1_001.gz R-K4_NNNN_KQ9_R1_001.gz D-K4_NNNN_M987_R1_001.gz _R-K4_NNNN_M987_R1_001.gz"`

For each entry, I need to return whether it starts with 'R' or 'D'. In order to do this, I need to ignore any character that comes before it. So, I wrote this regular expression:

`for i in $my_string; do echo $i | grep -E -o "^*?[RD]"; done`

However, this is only returning `R` or `D` for entries which are not preceded by a character.

How do I get this regex to return the `R` or `D` value in every case, whether there is a character in front of it or not? Keep in mind that the only thing which can be 'hard-coded' into the expression is the pattern to be matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be easy if you use `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^.?([RD]).*$/\1/'
```

i.e.

```
for i in $my_string; do echo $i | sed -r 's/^.?([RD]).*$/\1/'; done
```

---

Update:

Here is what each part of the command means:

```
-r : extended regular expression, although I think -e should work but
     turns out that during my testing, in order to use capturing group
     in regex, I need -r.  Anyway, not the main point
```

The script can be read as:

```
s/XXXX/YYYY/  : substitude from XXXX to YYYY
```

The "from" pattern (XXXX) means:

```
^    : start with
.?   : zero or one occurence of any character
(    : start of group
[RD] : either R or D
)    : end of group (which means, the group will contains either R or D
.*   : any number of any character
$    : till the end
```

the "to" pattern (YYYY):

```
\1   : content of capture group 1 in the "from" pattern (which is the "R or D")
```

Comment: would you be able to explain what each part of this `sed` command are doing? Thanks.

Comment: sure, updating the answer for more detail

Answer (score 3):

Use a parameter expansion to remove the prefix before using grep:

```
for i in $my_string; do echo ${i#[^RD]} | grep -o "^[RD]" ; done
```

or use a simple test without grep (since you already know that each item starts with a R or a D):

```
for i in $my_string; do
    if [[ $i =~ ^[^D]?R ]] ; then
       echo 'R'
    else
       echo 'D'
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

This regex worked in my local tests. Please have a try:

```
^.?[RD]
```

I can't think of a way to ONLY return the letter you want. I'd have a command after to detect whether the returned string is greater than 1 character long, and if so, I'd return only the second character.

Comment: That returns the R/D, along with any preceeding character. Somehow, I had accomplished this early but my implementation broke when I changed something elsewhere in the pipeline.

Comment: The 'edit' of this answer seems to claim pre/post processing of match results is not possible. :(

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061162/regex-to-match-a-pattern-and-exclude-a-part-of-the-string

Comment: Building on this did work as an alternative solution for me. I used the following: `echo "$my_string" | grep -E -o "^.?[RD]" | grep -E -o "[RD]"`. Doing this, the first grep returned the `R` or `D` along with any preceeding character, while the second grep returns just the `R` or `D` alone. Not as elegant so I did not end up using it, but it was useful if `sed` still seems too confusing to set up.  At this point I have figured out enough of `sed` and more about regex to just use that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure of what you are asking ( i understood you want to match only R and D at the beginning of a filename, whatever the character before it, if there is one ), but I think you should use [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), in php you would do

```
$re = "/(?<=^\S|\s\S|\s)[RD]/"; 
$str = "-D-K4_NNNN_M116_R1_001.gz _D-K4_NNNN_M56_R1_001.gz R-K4_NNNN_KQ9_R1_001.gz D-K4_NNNN_M987_R1_001.gz _R-K4_NNNN_M987_R1_001.gz"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

You can see the output [here](https://3v4l.org/HBB8n).

To use Perl syntax in bash you must enable it. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84477/forcing-bash-to-use-perl-regex-engine

You can test your regexp here if you need https://regex101.com/r/vV3nS3/1

Answer (score 2):

This does it when using the modifier 'g' for global: `(^| ).?(R|D)`

See the [regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/rW4hT5/1)